# chrome desktop notifications get text

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have chrome plugin, that checks given URL and use '`get`' method to check the return HTML code. if thee are errors - chrome notifications will pop. I want to create a button and whenever the notification button will be clicked, an alert will pop with the notification text.
I am not able to find any source of information on how to do this, and I will be happy if someone can help me with this
I've already try to search examples, on the web and on Google's website but without any luck

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: @peacetype i tried to find something related to chrome.notifications.get, but withouy any luck. the soutce code isn't relevant because it's working and i only beed to know how to so this particular thing :)

Comment: You might want to start [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications), it is the documentation regarding chrome notifications. It talks about notifications, how to create, the attributes at permissions needed. Hope this helps.